# EXCEL Data extraction, C# ASP.NET not working Console working

Tags: c#, asp.net, interop

I have some code that parses an excel file for data.
It works in C# console but not in ASP.net.

For some reason the snippet below fails in my asp.net application:
After the Cells[i,j] no intellisense is provided and the value2 property is missing.

Help, both apps are referencing using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

var g = xlRange.Cells[i, j].value2.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

[Interop is not supported in sever-scenarios (like ASP.NET) by MS.](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2)

There are many options to read/edit/create Excel files without Interop:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (XLSX only)

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (XLSX only)